# Hierarchy structure for browser game development

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking into creating browser game development. I have a strong background in C programming (c/c++/c#) and web development (html/css/wordpress/some JS). This area of programming seems like chaos and no one has a firm framework that works well and is good.

I've been exploring at libraries available such as [gameQueryJs](http://gamequeryjs.com/documentation/first-tutorial/first-tutorial-step-1/) and other tutorials I've found such as [Canvas Tutorial](http://billmill.org/static/canvastutorial/), I keep running into the same issue.

They all just jump STRAIGHT into the code. No pre-set up, how the HTML page should look like, just nothing. They all go BANG, right into the javascript.

Before I get into the javascript I need to set up the web page. I am wondering how such a page would be designed like and how to import scripts correctly.

For example, if I wanted to add jquery and the gamequery libary, would I add it like this?

```
<html>
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
     <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/jquery.gamequery-0.7.1.js"></script>
     <title> GAME TITLE </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="game-txt">
        <h1> GAME TITLE </h1>
    </div>  
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="canvascontainter">
            <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas> -- ignore this, this was when I was playing with the canvas tutorial
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
<!-- SCRIPT STUFF DOWN HERE? -->
```

To further explain my issue, here is gameQueryJS's first line of code they introduce to you to use.

```
var PLAYGROUND_HEIGHT = 250;
    var PLAYGROUND_WIDTH = 700;

    $("#playground").playground({height: PLAYGROUND_HEIGHT, width: PLAYGROUND_WIDTH});
```

Where does that go? What is the playground id they are manipulating on the page? They just throw that line at you like every other tutorial I've found without explaining anything.

Comment: If you are unsure how to structure a webpage properly, don't jump straight in to game dev tutorials. Learn the basics. Tutorials covering this sort of subject will (rightly) assume that their audience aren't, or at least _shouldn't be_, absolute beginners.

Comment: Oh no, I know how to structure a webpage properly. That's not an issue. 

I'm relating this to game development souly. Click on the gamequery link in my question. You will see at the bottom the scripts they are talking about adding. Where on earth do I add those?

Comment: Please explain why the down votes? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript can be placed in script tags or in a seperate file just like the gameQueryJs libraries that you are loading.

Where you put the script tags is almost entirely up to you, although most people will put them in the  section.

Putting them below the closing tag of the page  is not correct however. Unfortunately most browsers will accept and execute it even then because they try quite hard to make every page they get served work. For more on where to place script tags check [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp)

The playground they refer to is an element that you'd have on your page, in their example from lesson one it is a div with the id playground.

Also, if you check the first example that they give you can select Edit with JSFiddle the code they show there should help anwser part of your question as well as add to the lack of information you complained about.

Comment: In relation to the JSFiddle, does the demo not work for you? I try to check it out and it does not work. 

But thank you for pointing that out, I completely missed that.

Comment: Unfortunately the demo does not work for me either. I could not figure out why though :(